# How to handle the QueryExceptions(SOQL) effectively in apex class WITH USER_MODE?

Tags: soql, queryexception

> I'm trying to do a Query WITH USER_MODE in apex class.

I'm Querying an object without the permission in user_mode.

I got this error

sObject type 'Test__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

the above error is generic. I don't know how to differentiate that this error caused due to object has no permission.

can any one help me to differentiate that this error caused due to object has no permission and handle QueryException on different exception scenarios.

Thanks.

Comment: What API version does your Apex class have? They changed exception raising behaviour in 58.

Comment: @PhilW thanks, api version 58.